# SharePoint Calendar on the Home Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I'd like to add a calendar where I can view the entire month in a Calendar view with events I can add. When I go to edit my page, I click add web parts and I'm given the option to add a group calendar. After syncing this to my Office 365, I essentially see a list of upcoming events.

I'm looking to add a calendar where it's in a grid view like an actual calendar. I'd also like to add events to it as you'd see in a normal, everyday planner. How do I get this type of calendar onto my homepage and not just in my quick links section?

By the way, I am using SharePoint online. Thanks!

Comment: did you help my answer?

Answer (score 1):

For displaying calendar on Home Page you can easily use this Iframe, which you will add into Iframe web part in New Look SharePoint Pages.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx" scrolling="no" style="margin-left: -200px; margin-top: -200px;">
```

- The URL should be url of the view you want to use.

We are using this, or you must create your own web part, which will display calendar records in calendar view.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB calendar control for modern pages. Options:

1. Try out the new events web part anyway. It's not a calendar, but it gets the job done for upcoming events
2. Teach users how to get to and use the group calendar
3. Add a calendar to the page via the embed web part. To do this, see [this post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/calendar-web-part-on-modern-pages/td-p/161291). The summary is to add a calendar list to the site, then get put the url into an iframe, and use the embed web part to put the iframe on the page. Note, this technique is a disaster for mobile devices, and so I personally prefer the first two options, listed above.